# Each natural number is the set of all its predecessors.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Below is taken from page 41 of the book Classic Set Theory.

[image]

The set of natural numbers is defined as the smallest inductive set.

How do I show that each natural number is the set of all its predecessors, for example $10=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ and why does this observation "the set $n$ contains intuitively, $n$ elements" involves a circularity?

Comment: Well, you know $\forall m<n,\;m\subseteq n$

Comment: Your question "How do I show that each natural number is the set of all its predecessors" will depend on how natural numbers are defined in the book you are quoting from. But you did not include the definition in your question, making it impossible to answer.

Comment: @RushabhMehta it should be $m$ is a proper subset of $n$

Comment: Prove that the set $\{n\in\mathbb N\mid n\subseteq\mathbb N\}\subseteq\mathbb N$ is inductive. That implies $\{n\in\mathbb N\mid n\subseteq\mathbb N\}=\mathbb N$ or equivalently "every element of a natural number is again a natural number".

Comment: @drhab I have done the proof.

Comment: Good. Does this result bring satisfaction concerning your question?

Comment: @drhab No. I still don't see a reason why $10 = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$

Comment: $10$ is defined as $9\cup\{9\}$ so if $9=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ then $10=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$. This shifts the question to: how to prove that $9=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$? Again this question can be shifted and within a finite number of shiftings it is enough to prove that $0=\varnothing$ which is true by definition.

Comment: You could prove that the set $\{n\in\mathbb N\mid n\text{ is the set of all its predecessors }\}$ is an inductive set. Tricky however is the question: "what exactly is a predecessor"?

Comment: @drhab So it all just because of the design of symbols for numbers? Because we name the empty set as 0, its successor as 1, the successor of 1 to be 2, and so for.

Comment: Essential is that every element of a natural is again a natural number (see my first comment). Then if you start *naming* them by the familiar symbols $0,1,2,\dots$ as done in your question then this leads to things like $10=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.